# Netbeans/Java: reference a jar but not deploy it

Tags: netbeans, ant

I want to build a jar containing a class which I have derived from a class in second jar. I add a reference to the second jar in my project but then Netbeans copies that jar to dist/lib which I don't really want. Is there a way to reference the second jar at compile time but not have it copied.

Specifically, I am making a custom task for Ant so I derive from org.apache.tools.ant.Task and I don't want ant.jar copied to dist/lib.

This is with Netbeans 7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of achieving this is to 'Uncheck' the **Copy Dependent Libraries** check box, which will ensure that no **JAR** files are copied to `dist` folder.

Exact Steps:

1. Right click on the project name and choose **Properties** option from the context menu, this will open the **Project Properties** dialog box.
2. Select the **Build > Packaging** node from the **Categories** tree view and **uncheck** the **Copy Dependent Libraries** check box
3. Now build the project and check that no **JAR** files for libraries are copied to `dist` folder.